# iPhone "touchesBegan" and "touchesMoved" message ... do not move to centre of touch

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitouch

I am modifying the "MoveMe" example from the apple web site. When my controller gets the "touchesMoved" message it moves the object being moved to the centre of the touch, because (pseudocode) object.center = touch.center. How can I store the offset of the initial touch so that if I start the touch/drag to the side my finger will stay on that spot while I drag it around?

Comment: Yes, please explain a bit better.

Comment: @DyingCactus: ok, explained a bit better :)

Comment: Tuomas and Macmade are essentially correct then and you can upvote or accept if their answer helps.  You'll need two CGFloat ivars to store the x and y offset which you set in touchesBegan and use in the touchesMoved method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store target_view.frame in an instance variable when touchBegan message arrives.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you store that in an instance variable of your class?