# Help me understand iPhone touchesBegan implementation and dragging a UIView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, drag, touchesbegan

I know this has been sort of answered before ( [iPhone "touchesBegan" and "touchesMoved" message ... do not move to centre of touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438504) ), but I'm very new to iPhone development so don't understand the answer.

Essentially, what I want to do is have a UIImageView which responds to touches, to move it around the screen.  The sample from Apple has the view that when it has touchesBegan, moves its centre to the touch, then moves the view.

What I'd like is for the image to pan like when you use the UIImagePicker.  The selected image does not snap to the touch, but instead will move from the touch.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to get the point where you first touched the screen. Then for each 'touch moved' get the delta x and y coordinates for the new point and move the image by that amount.

```
// This is untested code and I can't even be sure if it compiles
// Hopefully it is verbose enough to help you with that you are
// Trying to do. If not I can update once I get back infront of 
// a Mac.
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint delta = currentPoint - lastPoint;

    currentViewLoc = imageView.center;

    imageView.center.x = currentViewLoc.x - delta.x;
    imageView.center.y = currentViewLoc.y - delta.y;

    currentPoint = lastPoint;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject]; 
    currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}
```

something like that anyway. I hope you get the idea of what I am trying to say.

Comment: I really appreciate the time taken to answer, however as a complete beginner, it would be really useful to see how this is actually used?